# Modify dynamically scroll view items

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I would like to perform a dynamic management of a scroll view that contains multiple lines.
Each line contains a label and a text field. A configuration file will be parsed to specify which field should be displayed and which one should be deleted.

I have tried to put each line (label + text field) into a view and embed all views into the scroll view using stroyboard editor. Then I made a reference to each view in the viewController.h file:

@property (weak, nonatomic)IBOutlet UIView* view_x;

I tried then to delete all views and restore them one by one:

[scollView addSubview:view_x];

The result that I got is that the view is not put in the right place in the scroll view and the displayed view is blurred.

Can anyone help me to find a solution to my problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a UITableView, as it support scrolling, adding, deleting, etc without you having to reinvent all that logic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, does the UITableview support adding a text field and label into the same line?

Comment: Yes, there is support for having multiple fields in a table cell; Apple has provided lots of documentation and sample code; start here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html